# Asynchronous Operations in SolrNet

Tags: .net, multithreading, solr, task-parallel-library, solrnet

Is it possible to make asynchronous operations in SolrNET that follow the APM (begin, end) pattern? I need to make several asynchronous calls to different Solr search indexes in my Asp.NET web application and I am trying to reduce the load on the thread pool by using non-blocking threads. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least looking through [the SolrNet source](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet), while the IHttpWebRequest interface includes Begin/End pairs, those aren't used/exposed higher in the interfaces (like ISolrConnection), so AFAICT you'd have to change (or reimplement) those to support it.

That said, it's likely worth just trying it as-is (kicking them off with Task.Run or the like) and seeing whether you really end up starving the threadpool - if you do, you can reconfigure it with higher limits, after all. :)

Making SolrNet Task-based via TAP would likely be a good chunk of effort since you typically need to do async/Task through all the levels of the stack (and in the case of SolrNet, probably should just do so in a fork that targets 4.5 so it can rely on the new HttpClient and its native Task-based calls)

Comment: If anyone's going to work on this, please do not use .NET 4+ async. I don't plan to abandon .NET 3.5 any time soon, so use begin/end (which can then be trivially wrapped in Task)